# Django MYSQL JQGRID won't display since SSL / HTTPS

Tags: mysql, django, apache, jqgrid

I successfully deployed my very first Django / Mysql / Ubuntu /Apache - mod_wsgi application on an OVH VPS.

On the main page, I have a JQGRID table to display some informations from my MYSQL DB (hosted on the VPS as well).

I'm lost because everything is working like a charm as lons as I don't enable SSL certificate.

http://example.com displays everything correctly(including the JQGRID filled with MYSQL)

https://example.com displays the Django app, with the static files and images BUT NO JQGRID table appear

I have made a search engine to filter the results on the JQGRID and same behaviour :

http://example.com -> the filter is working and display the results

https://example.com -> I have an error 500. I turned the DEBUG=TRUE on django to have some details and this is what i get after clicking the search button :

MultiValueDictKeyError at /
'username'

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://example.com/
Django Version: 4.1.6
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'username'
Exception Location: /var/www/example/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py, line 86, in **getitem**
Raised during:  example_app.views.home
Python Executable:  /var/www/example/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.11.2

views.py error

[image]

I can't figure if the problem come from django , apache or MYSQL ?
and why it's happening only with HTTPS ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JAVASCRIPT console of the web browser i noticed this error :

```
[blocked] The page at https://example.com/ was not allowed to run insecure content 
from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js.
```

So i want to my django home page and update
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js.
to
http**S**://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js.

and it solved the problem.